# Correctly handling backpressure from an async call

Tags: java, rx-java3

I have some code that looks roughly like this:

```
Completable handle(Observable<Object> inbound) {
  return inbound.buffer(1, TimeUnit.Second, 250)
    .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
    .flatMapToCompletable(this::sendToClient);
}

Completable sendToClient(List<Object> list) {
  // call IO asynchronously
}
```

`inbound` is a cold observable that is producing in a standard while loop (but on another Thread!). While not disposed, fetch some data and call `onNext()`.

The issue I face is that `sendToClient` is too "slow", it can't keep up with the speed at which `inbound` is producing data. It's an async operation that is essentially queuing the calls to the client in memory somewhere (don't have access to this code) and eventually filling the heap.

I need a way to figure out a way to get `inbound` to stop producing when these calls start to stack up. Is there a way to achieve this using inbuild operators?

Comment: Instead of stop producing, perhaps don't attempt to send if there is another IO call in progress (or some pending count > threshold)?

Comment: @AndrewS - I don't have access into that code. I don't know how much is queued.

Comment: You could consider using `Flowable.generate` that does offer backpressure, however, the timed `buffer` would remain an issue as it unbounds the flow. If you can just use the size-bound `buffer` alternative, that would improve this latter situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably suggest creating a thread pool to handle the sendToClient operations.  This can support having a queue of requests waiting to be handled, but you can also specify behavior if the queue is full (ie, too much back pressure).

Take a look at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to this call. `sendToClient` is provided by a lib.